# Pushdown Automata

Tags: automata

I having trouble constructing NPDAs for these two languages:

$L_1 = \{a^nb^m \mid 2n \le m \le 3n\}$

$L_2 = \{a^nb^mc^k \mid n = m \: or \: m \ne k\}$

Would these be the proper states for the first one?

- $q_0$ – reading $a$’s (initial state)
- $q_1$ – reading $b$’s and popping $A$’s
- $q_2$ – reading $b$’s
- $q_f$ – ﬁnal state

Would these be the proper states for the second one?

- $q_0$ – reading $a$’s (initial state)
- $q_1$ – reading $b$’s and popping $A$’s
- $q_2$ – reading $b$’s and pushing $B$’s
- $q_3$ – reading $c$’s
- $q_f$ – ﬁnal state

I do not think I am approaching this properly. This is not non deterministic right? How should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** for (a): I think you need more states than you said.  Here's my idea.

Every time the machine reads an `a`, it should push a token on the stack.  Eventually there will  be $n$ tokens on the stack.

When the machine  starts seeing `b`s it should use its finite control to keep count of how many it has seen.  After it reads 2 `b`s, it should nondeterministically decide between:

1. reading one more `b`, then resetting the counter to 0 and popping a token from the stack, or
2. resetting the counter and popping the stack *without* reading another `b`.

The computation that chooses (1)  every time will empty the stack after reading exactly $3n$ `b`s; the computation that chooses (2) every time will empty the stack after reading exactly $2n$ `b`s; a computation that chooses some of each will empty the stack after reading some intermediate number of `b`s.  So if the number of `b`s is in the right range, *some* computation will make the right sequence of choices and empty the stack just as the input ends.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by counter? I am trying to describe these with $\delta$ functions.

Comment: The finite state of the PDA can store a finite amount of information.  A counter is a series of states, say $s_0, s_1, \ldots, s_n$, with $\delta(s_i, \mathtt{b}) = s_{i+1}$.  The idea is that if the machine is in state $s_i$, that means it has counted $i$ `b` symbols. When the machine is in state $s_0$ it knows it has not seen any `b` symbols yet. When it is in state $s_1$, it knows it has seen one `b` symbol, because $\delta(s_0, \mathtt{b}) = s_1$.  Similarly in state $s_2$ the machine knows it has seen two `b` symbols. To reset the counter simply means to return to state $s_0$.

Comment: @user314159 It is much easier to design machines by thinking of counters and variables than by thinking directly in terms of states. Once you have the design done, it is easy to implement the required counters and variables as machine states. For example, [here is a machine that has two counters](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/747540/25554), one counting how many `0`s and one counting how many `1`s it has seen. The machine accepts the input if it has seen at least two `0`s and at most two `1`s.

Comment: I posted an answer below because it was too big for here, does that make sense?

Comment: Also is $L_2 = \{a^nb^mc^k \mid n = m \: or \: m \ne k\}$ even a CFL?

Comment: It is the union of $\{a^nb^mc^k\mid n=m\}$ and $\{a^nb^mc^k\mid m\ne k\}$, both of which are CFLs.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So for the first part I have that $\delta(q_0,a,z)=(q_1,az)$; $\delta(q_0,\lambda,z)=(q_3,\lambda)$; $\delta(q_1,a,a)=(q_1,aa)$; $\delta(q_1,b,a)=(q_2,\lambda)$; $\delta(q_2,b,a)=(q_2,\lambda)$; $\delta(q_2,\lambda,z)=(q_3,\lambda)$. I think that works for the first half, but how do I approach it when $m \ne k$?

Comment: $\{a^nb^mc^k\mid m\ne k\}$ is the union of $\{a^nb^mc^k\mid m<k\}$ and $\{a^nb^mc^k\mid m>k\}$.

Comment: So for {$a^nb^mc^k | m<k$} it would be $\delta(q_0,b,z)=(q_1,bz)$; $\delta(q_1,b,b)=(q_1,bb)$; $\delta(q_1,c,b)=(q_2,\lambda)$; $\delta(q_2,c,b)=(q_2,\lambda)$; $\delta(q_2,c,z)=(q_3,z)$; $\delta(q_3,c,z)=(q_3,z)$? 

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

I think I am beginning to understand this. I do not know how to do a diagram on here so this description might be a little rough:

$\rightarrow q_0$$\rightarrow (a,0,11)$$\rightarrow q_1 $$\rightarrow (b,11,\lambda) \: and \: (b,111,\lambda)$$\rightarrow q_2$$\rightarrow (\lambda,0,\lambda)$$\rightarrow q_3$

with $q_1 \rightarrow (a,1,11) \rightarrow q_1$

and $q_2 \rightarrow (b,11,\lambda) \: and \: (b,111, \lambda) \rightarrow q_2$

So the delta functions would be:
$\delta(q_0,a,0) = (q_1,10)$;
$\delta(q_0,\lambda,0) = (q_3,\lambda)$;
$\delta(q_1,a,1) = (q_1,11)$;
$\delta(q_1,b,11) = (q_2,\lambda)$;
$\delta(q_1,b,111) = (q_2,\lambda)$;
$\delta(q_2,b,11) = (q_2,\lambda)$;
$\delta(q_2,b,111) = (q_2,\lambda)$;
$\delta(q_1,b,11) = (q_2,\lambda)$;
$\delta(q_2,\lambda,0) = (q_3,\lambda)$;

Does this make sense?